# Affine varieties over finite fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, affine-geometry, projective-space

I read in this paper (http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~srg/preprints/Chandigarh.pdf) that the following set is an affine variety:

$V_f=\{(t_0,...,t_N)\in \mathbb{F}_p^{N+1} : f(t_0,...,t_N)=0 \}$ where $f$ is an irreducible polynomial.

According to the same paper, the following set would be a projective variety:

$V_g=\{(x,y,w,z)\in \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_p}^3 : xy-wz=0 \}$ where $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_p}^3$ is a 3-dimensional projective space over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

What's the dimension and degree of $V_g$?

Comment: There is no requirement in algebraic geometry for the base field to be algebraically closed.

Comment: It is a bit unusual IMO (YMMV). If $f$ is absolutely irreducible, then it probably would work without anything too strange happening.

Comment: I think if the polynomial is not irreducible then the variety is not irreducible. I think the aforementioned set is called an algebraic set if the variety is not irreducible.

Comment: Thank you Relapsarian! I edited the question.

Comment: Something is wrong here, because a point in $\mathbb{P}^4$ should have *five* coordinates, not four.  I looked through the paper and couldn't seem find a reference to $V_g$ -- what page is it on?

Comment: Dear @Daniel: if $t$ is the fifth coordinate in $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_p}^4$, the OP's equation describes a $3$-dimensional cone  $V_g\subset \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_p}^4$. That cone has  as summit the point $(x:y:z:w:t)=(0:0:0:0:1)$ and as base the $2$-dimensional quadric in $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_p}^3$ given by the equation $xy-wz=0$.

Comment: To the OP: the variety $V_g$ is  described in my comment to @Daniel. It has dimension $3$ and degree $2$. Its only singularity is its summit.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Of course, but the OP has written 
$$V_g = \{(x, y, z, w) \; | \; \ldots \},$$
not 
$$V_g = \{(x, y, z, w, t) \; | \; \ldots \}.$$
Of course that could simply be a typo.  That's why I was looking to see if $V_g$ was shown in the paper

Comment: Dear @Daniel, you are absolutely right. I hadn't read the OP's incorrectly  formulated  question attentively enough : my apologies to you for that. Your comment asking about the page in the reference was clearly the correct reaction.

Comment: Dear @Daniel, I'm sorry for the typo. I fixed it. The example is not in the paper, it was my own question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so
$$xy - wz = 0$$
cuts a quadric surface -- that is, a two-dimensional variety of degree 2 -- out of $\mathbb{P}^3$.

In order to see the dimension you really have to work scheme-theoretically, so that you see all of the non-$\mathbb{F}_p$-rational points of the variety -- otherwise it just appears to be a finite set of points, which would be zero-dimensional.

However, assuming you're willing to concede that a single equation cuts a two-dimensional variety out of three-dimensional space, it's not hard to calculate the degree of the intersection.  Since $3 = 2 + 1$, we can determine this by intersecting our surface with a general line in $\mathbb{P}^3$.  Let's take, say, the line $x = y = 0$.  Substituting this into the equation for our surface, we have $x = y = w z = 0$.  There are two solutions to this system of equations, namely $[0:0:1:0]$ and $[0:0:0:1]$.  (In principle we should worry that the line we chose was somehow exceptional, but for now let's not.)  Since the surface meets a linear subspace of complimentary dimension in two points, it has degree 2.